How to show/hide Date input depending on which status is selected in the form?
In a Laravel 10 / Nova 4.27 app, I want to show the published_at field in the editor only if the status field has the value ACTIVE. Here is my current code:
    Badge::make(__('Status'), 'status')->required()
        ->options(ProductStatusEnum::getStatusSelectionItems())->hideFromDetail()->hideWhenUpdating()
        ->colors(ProductStatusEnum::getStatusColors(hexValue: true))->displayUsingLabels(),

    Date::make(__('Published at'), 'published_at')
        ->displayUsing(fn($value) => $value ? DateConv::getFormattedDateTime($value) : '--')
        ->showOnDetail(function () use ($status) { // in view mode "/nova/resources/products/17"
            return $status === ProductStatusEnum::ACTIVE;
        })
        ->showOnUpdating(function () use ($status) { // in edit mode "/nova/resources/products/17/edit"
            return $status === ProductStatusEnum::ACTIVE;
        })
        ->sortable(),

This setup works as expected when I open an existing model. However, is there a way to reactively show or hide the published_at date input in the form, depending on which status is selected?
UPDATED BLOCK #1:
If I try $field->visible code by @Jon Menard I got error :
Method Laravel\Nova\Fields\Date::visible does not exist.

In Dependent Fields block of  docs there are hide/show methods example.
I try to follow it with code and defining depends method:
Date::make(__('Published at'), 'published_at')
    ->displayUsing(fn($value) => $value ? DateConv::getFormattedDateTime($value) : '--')
    ->hide()
    ->dependsOn(['status'], function (Date $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
        // Check if the status is 'ACTIVE'
        \Log::info(' -000 $formData->string(status)::');
        \Log::info(json_encode($formData->string('status')));

    })

But checking in log file value of $formData->string(status) I see empty
string(maybe because I use enum for status field(not simple string)).
I tried to debug values of $field, $formData vars butI did not how I can status field from them...
I checked file vendor/laravel/nova/src/Fields/FormData.php, it has some methods, but nothing for enum field.
Any hints how get value of status field inside of dependsOn block ?

Take a look at the dependsOn functionality of a Laravel Nova Field.
Something like this might work:
Date::make(__('Published at'), 'published_at')
    ->displayUsing(fn($value) => $value ? DateConv::getFormattedDateTime($value) : '--')
    ->sortable()
    ->dependsOn(['status'], function (Date $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
        $field->hide();
        // Check if the status is 'ACTIVE'
        if ($formData->status === ProductStatusEnum::ACTIVE->value) {
             $field->show();
        }
    }),


Thanks for the provided link.
Please look at UPDATED BLOCK #1

Try my updated version

With changed code : ProductStatusEnum::ACTIVE->value - it works ok, as $formData var has string value in status field. Please change your answer and I will acccept it.

@mstdmstd you got it!
